# How do I download NSData, change metadata, and convert it back to NSData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, type-conversion, metadata, nsdata

I'm trying to download an .mp4/.m4a, change the metadata (background image), and convert it back to NSData so it can be copied to clipboard. As you can see by the code below. `_artworkData` and `_previewData` are not empty.

```
UIImage *artworkImage = [UIImage imageWithData:_artworkData];
NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];

                NSString *path = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"File.mp4"]];
                NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"path"];
                [_previewData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
                ANMovie* file = [[ANMovie alloc] initWithFile:path]; // or .mp4
                NSData* jpegCover = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(artworkImage, 1.0);
                _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:jpegCover];
                ANMetadata* metadata = [[ANMetadata alloc] init];
                metadata.albumCover = [[ANMetadataImage alloc] initWithImageData:jpegCover type:ANMetadataImageTypeJPG];
                [file setMovieMetadata:metadata];
                [file close];

                _previewData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
                UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
                NSDictionary *imageItem=@{@"public.mpeg-4-audio":self.previewData};
                NSDictionary *textItem=@{@"public.plain-text":self.linkData};

                pasteboard.items=@[imageItem,textItem];
```

The following code does not work and stops on the following line logging a random 10 digit number.

```
NSDictionary *imageItem=@{@"public.mpeg-4-audio":self.previewData};
```

Is this not working because I have to convert .m4a to .mp4 or something? It seems editing metadata on either or would work.